# Linking libfftw3-3.lib in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, linker, fftw

I am trying to get a simple project working with FFTW in Visual Studio 2010.  I am having trouble linking the library.

I've created 64 bit .lib files as directed on [their Windows page](http://fftw.org/install/windows.html)

I unzipped the 64 bit version of their download and ran the specified tools in that directory.  I've unzipped it in a folder called "fftw" as a sibling of my project.

In Visual Studio I've created a C++ Console App with all the defaults.  The default build type is Debug Win32.  I've added this line to *Configuration Properties→Linker*:
`C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\fftw\libfftw3-3.lib`

I've also added libfftw3-3.lib to *Configuration Properties→Linker→Input* and tried a full path there.

I include StdLib complex and FFTW:

```
#include <complex>
#include "..\..\fftw\fftw3.h"
```

My main function just has their example code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  const int N = 1024;
  fftw_complex in[N], out[N];
  fftw_plan p;
  p = fftw_create_plan(N, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_one(p, in, out);
  fftw_destroy_plan(p);  
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to build I get this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FFTTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  FFTTest.cpp
1>c:\users\XXXXX\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ffttest\ffttest\ffttest.cpp(34): error C3861: 'fftw_create_plan': identifier not found
1>c:\users\XXXXX\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ffttest\ffttest\ffttest.cpp(36): error C3861: 'fftw_one': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can someone show me the error in my ways?

Comment: Whatever happened to the plan to use the 64-bit version of the libraries?  Your test project is 32-bit.

Comment: I just tried with the 32-bit binaries from FFTW for my 32-bit project.  I get the same error.  I extracted the .h, .dll, and .def from their 32-bit package.  Then here's what I ran on the prompt to create the .lib and .exp

    C...Projects\fftw>lib /def:libfftw3-3.def /machine:x86
    Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.40219.01
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    
       Creating library libfftw3-3.lib and object libfftw3-3.exp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: `fftw_create_plan()` and `fftw_one()` are functions that have been removed from FFTW3.

You might have got the code from [FFTW2 tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html), see the [FFTW3 tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backslash in paths:

```
#include "../../fftw/fftw3.h"
```

A backslash in C/C++ is interpreted as an escape character, to produce a backslash you need to double it, but generally always use `/` to make path separators.

Comment: No dice, Charles.  Same error messages.  Also, not important, but the backslash seems to work fine.  fftw_complex and fftw_plan are defined in the .h file and I don't get any errors for those identifiers.

Comment: is it in a namespace or something?

Comment: I don't think so... I don't see these defined in the .h file either.  Is that a problem?  What is the command to list the entry points in a .lib/.exp file?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use FFTW v2 APIs with the FFTW v3 libraries.  A working example is on their [v3 tutorial page](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Tutorial.html#Tutorial).

The steps I have above to reference the library are fine.  You also might want to put the FFTW DLL into the directory where your executable is.